# Difference between wise and clever?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between clever and wise

As far as I understand, a **wise** person has knowledge and skills of everything but it's not necessary that his intentions are evil.

But a **clever** person always has evil intentions.

Comment: Wherever did you get those ideas? Please show some sources.

Comment: You provided your personal definition about the two words, mind sharing why do you think those are their respective definitions and where did you get those (definitions) as well? :)

Answer (score 4):

> Wise: having the power of discerning and judging properly as to what is true or right; possessing discernment, judgment, or discretion. [Source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/wise)
>
> Clever: mentally bright; having sharp or quick intelligence; able. [Source](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/clever)

Clever generally has something to do with intelligence. A "clever kid" is a "bright kid," a "smart kid." Someone who is clever can usually problem-solve faster, run through possibilities or probabilities quicker and more accurately, perform mental math easily (or at least easier than less naturally clever people), and the like. Cleverness is often innate, but can sometimes be learned. For most people, cleverness can be linked to [IQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligence_quotient).

Wisdom comes with age and experience. Wisdom is the ability to not only know something, but explain that to someone much less experienced (who may or may not be more clever). If you are a really smart kid and your parents aren't as "quick" or "clever" as you are, I can promise you they are much more wise, and will more often than not be correct. Again, wisdom comes from age coupled with experience.

Comment: I read in the holy bible that snake was the wisest of all so i thought that means someone who is intelligent but decieving,manipulative, or a cunning person

Comment: @user236989 That's partly a matter of translation, and I've read it as "cleverest" for the snake also. However, neither word means that someone is correct, or using their gifts for "good". You can be extremely clever, and help people with that, or you can be extremely clever and be a hacker or a conman. You can also be very wise, and encourage people, or be very wise, and use that to take advantage of people.

Comment: I associate **clever** with cheating. I like **smart** and **wise**.

Comment: @SovereignSun well, know that that is not what everyone will do :)

Comment: @SovereignSun - _“Time is so mysterious. Only Einstein was clever and bold enough to think of it in a manner contrary to traditions.”_ (The Logic of Time in the Universe, Samuel K.K. Blankson, 2011) _"Edison was a clever, determined inventor whose activities excited the public imagination toward the practical uses of electricity. He pioneered in, among other things, the generation and distribution of electric power for lighting.”_ (Foundations of Electric Circuits, J. R. Cordell, 1999)